# What is the meaning of the double v marked(prettier) on the vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier-vscode

What is the difference between one or two V check marks on the vscode?

In particular, what is the meaning of the double v marked?

[V Checkmarks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4xRY.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, that is not a 'v' but, it is a Tick Symbol aka a Check Symbol.

A Single Check represents that Prettier is enabled and working in your current environment and double-check symbol represents that your current document is "fine" according to the rules specified in the Prettier Extension.

Just for future references, refer to [this official documentation's article](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels) for the meaning of various icons/symbols used across Visual Studio Code.

Comment: OK! Tick Symbol. ^^
That's the relevant information on the official site. I think I need to study more.
Thank you so much for your kind and useful reply.